# SOLVED: Custom taxonomy conflict with Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I wrote a custom plugin which only sets a custom post type (dl), its taxonomy/category (downloads) and tag-like taxonomy (tagged).

It's on an already established site and the plugin has worked just fine for years. Now I wanted to add a Woocommerce store to my site but it's causing issues.

If I want to see a download category:

example.com/downloads/DownloadCategory1

it just shows 404 page.

Here's the code:

```
function dl_setup_post_types() {

    $dl_labels =  apply_filters( 'dl_labels', array(
        'name'                => 'Files',
        'singular_name'       => 'File',
        'add_new'             => __('Add New', 'dl'),
        'add_new_item'        => __('Add New File', 'dl'),
        'edit_item'           => __('Edit File', 'dl'),
        'new_item'            => __('New File', 'dl'),
        'all_items'           => __('All Files', 'dl'),
        'view_item'           => __('View File', 'dl'),
        'search_items'        => __('Search Files', 'dl'),
        'not_found'           => __('No Files found', 'dl'),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __('No Files found in Trash', 'dl'),
        'parent_item_colon'   => '',
        'menu_name'           => __('Files', 'dl'),
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        
    ) );


    $dl_args = array(
        'labels'            => $dl_labels,
        'public'            => true,
        'publicly_queryable'=> true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_in_menu'      => true,
        'show_in_rest' =>true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'capability_type'   => 'post',
        'has_archive'       => true,
        'hierarchical'      => false,
        'supports'          => apply_filters('dl_supports', array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'tags', 'comments', 'excerpt' ) ),
        'taxonomies' => array('downloads'),
    );
    register_post_type( 'dl', apply_filters( 'dl_post_type_args', $dl_args ) );

}

add_action('init', 'dl_setup_post_types');

function dl_categories() {
// set up labels
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => 'Download Categories',
        'singular_name'     => 'Download Category',
        'search_items'      => 'Search Download Categories',
        'all_items'         => 'All Download Categories',
        'edit_item'         => 'Edit Download Category',
        'update_item'       => 'Update Download Category',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Download Category',
        'new_item_name'     => 'New Download Category',
        'menu_name'         => 'Download Categories'
    );
    // register taxonomy
    register_taxonomy( 'downloads', 'dl', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_rest' =>true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'downloads',
        'hierarchical' => true,
            )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'dl_categories' );


/* Add tags */
add_action( 'init', 'dl_tags', 0 );
 
function dl_tags() {
 
// Labels part for the GUI
 
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Tags', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Tag', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Tags' ),
    'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Tags' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Tags' ),
    'parent_item' => null,
    'parent_item_colon' => null,
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Tag' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Tag' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Tag' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Tag Name' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate tags with commas' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove tags' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used tags' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Tags' ),
  ); 
 
// Now register the non-hierarchical taxonomy like tag
 
  register_taxonomy('tagged','dl',array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tagged' ),
  ));
}
```

I tried disabling Woocommerce -> the link starts working again.

I asked on the Woocommerce support forum but apparently it's not a WC issue and it's something to do with my plugin. I'm not really sure what could be wrong.

I've found similar problems on here and StackExchange (404 on custom taxonomy), but no solutions seem to be working. I tried adding

```
$GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->use_verbose_page_rules = true;
```

after register_taxonomy from advice on one such forum post. Didn't work.

I do flush the permalinks after every change to see if it worked.

**FIXED:** I changed the endpoint name for Downloads in Woocommerce settings -> Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your taxonomy a different name. Try replacing:

```
register_taxonomy( 'downloads'
```

With:

```
register_taxonomy('downloads_dl'
```

Then flush permalinks and check if it's working.

You probably won't have any posts, so you will have to click every post and give check it to new taxonomy, or you can just run a custom MySQL query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, Woocommerce isn't using any download taxonomy (https://woocommerce.com/document/installed-taxonomies-post-types/).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Did you try my advice and did it help you?

Comment: Sorry for replying late. I figured it out, and changed the Downloads endpoint in Woocommerce, that did the job.